# How to use Kalman filter model in detecting peaks

Tags: python, time-series, filtering, kalman-filter, pykalman

For my evaluation, I wanted to use [PyKalman](https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python/blob/master/10-Unscented-Kalman-Filter.ipynb) filter library. I have created a very small time series data ready with three columns formatted as follows. The full dataset is attached here for reproduciability since I can't attach a file on stackoverflow:

http://www.mediafire.com/file/el1tkrdun0j2dk4/testdata.csv/file

```
  time        X      Y
 0.040662  1.041667  1
 0.139757  1.760417  2
 0.144357  1.190104  1
 0.145341  1.047526  1
 0.145401  1.011882  1
 0.148465  1.002970  1
 ....      .....     .
```

I have read [the PyKalman library documetation](https://pykalman.github.io/#unscented-kalman-filter-user-s-guide) for Python  and managed to do a simple linear filtering using `Kalman Filter`and here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from pykalman import KalmanFilter 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



df = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')
print(df)
pd.set_option('use_inf_as_null', True)

df.dropna(inplace=True)


X = df.drop('Y', axis=1)
y = df['Y']



estimated_value= np.array(X)
real_value = np.array(y)

measurements = np.asarray(estimated_value)



kf = KalmanFilter(n_dim_obs=1, n_dim_state=1, 
                  transition_matrices=[1],
                  observation_matrices=[1],
                  initial_state_mean=measurements[0,1], 
                  initial_state_covariance=1,
                  observation_covariance=5,
                  transition_covariance=1)

state_means, state_covariances = kf.filter(measurements[:,1]) 
state_std = np.sqrt(state_covariances[:,0])
print (state_std)
print (state_means)
print (state_covariances)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.margins(x=0, y=0.05)

plt.plot(measurements[:,0], measurements[:,1], '-r', label='Real Value Input') 
plt.plot(measurements[:,0], state_means, '-b', label='Kalman-Filter') 
plt.legend(loc='best')
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.set_ylabel("Value")
plt.show()
```

Which gives the following plot as an output

[image]

As we can see from the plot and my [dataset](http://www.mediafire.com/file/el1tkrdun0j2dk4/testdata.csv/file), my input is non-linear. Therefore, I wanted to use `Kalman Filter` and see if I can detect and track the drops of the filtered signal (blue color in the above plot). But since I am so new to `Kalman Filter`, I seem to have a hardtime understanding the mathematical formulation and and to get started with `Unscented Kalman Filter`. I found a good example on basic use of [PyKalman UKF](https://github.com/pykalman/pykalman/blob/master/examples/unscented/plot_filter.py) - but it doesn't show how to defined the percentage of the drop (peaks). I would, therefore, appreciate for any help at least which detects how big the drop from the peaks of the filtered one is (for example, 50% or 80% of the previous drop of the blue line in the plot). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've asked by email repeatedly for help, but I don't understand your question at all.  You should ignore Kalman filters first and just explain what your data is, and what you want to learn from it or what you wish it would be.

Comment: A Kalman filter would be appropriate if: 1) you had some way to predict future round trip times from past round trip times, 2) you had more than one way to measure the round trip times, and 3) you have an estimate for how much error is present in those things.  Then the Kalman filter tells you how to mix the prediction and all of the measurements to get a best estimate.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just have no idea what you're asking.  "Detect the peaks"?  Like find a local maximum?  That is not related to Kalman filter.  "How high the drop is"? Like find the local minimum and subtract from the local maximum?  That is not related to Kalman filter.  "How do we define how high the peak drops"?  I don't know what that means.

Comment: @BenJackson, thank you and i know what you mean. Sorry for my bad expression but what I am trying to say is TCP has a change of state when there is packet loss or delay (represented by those peaks we see in the plot). So what I wanted to learn is if we manage to detect the changes - it will be possible to know what kind of TCP algorithm it is - that's my main goal. Hope it is clearer by now.